# Looking for a replacement relay

Tags: relay

I have an relay in an old device (a heated display case), that seems to be failing.

The relay is a Midtex 157-32U200, and the few distributors that I could find that carry this relay refuse to sell it to me as it's supposed to be a "restricted item" (I guess only machine resellers are allowed to buy it).

I've found something similar at my local electronics place - it's a generic relay named JQX-53F 32. The ratings seem to be similar, and while this relay has an additional bank of connectors in the middle row, the original one only used the outer rows, so I don't know if that would be of any relevance.
Obviously, I'm not an electrical engineer, so I don't know the first thing about relays, but perhaps somebody can help me find a suitable replacement for my dying old one.

I've attached the wiring diagram of the machine, and pictures of the old and new relay, so perhaps that'll help more than my amateurish explanations...

[image: Wiring Diagram]

[image: Old and new relay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ought to work fine, as long as your relay socket will accept the middle row of contacts. If not, see if you can find a JQX-53F 2Z, which ought to be a perfect match.

The only physical difference will be the lack of the mecbanical tab at the rear which is intended to lock the relay into the socket. However, since you have a stationary application with no shock or vibration this should not be an issue.

Comment: Luckily, the wires are connected individually (i.e. no socket), so connecting them is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using the unapproved (for safety) Chinese piece of 'stuff' unless you have absolutely no other choice.

It's usually a hindrance when you hide your location and ask for sources, by the way.

Digikey (ships most places, but more cheaply to the USA and Canada) has the Schrack [RM205730](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=RM2/3/7&DocType=DS&DocLang=English) for less than $20, for example. It's rated 230VAC coil and 16A contacts, and carries these safety agency markings:

[image]

Meaning it has been tested to (and passed) safety agency standards for Canada, the USA and Germany.

I have seen similar Chinese product marked with fake approval markings and dangerously defective, by the way.

I suggest you do a parametric search at a distributor such as Digikey or MSC (US industrial wholesaler) or McMaster (USA) and find something that fits the same mounting holes, has the same width of spade terminals, and has at least as good ratings on the contacts. You can check the datasheet against your sample part.

[image]